# How to get a String array with java code from <string-item> list in arrays.xml in Android?

Tags: android, mobile

I want to get an array of strings reading from arrays.xml file we add in android values/ folder. Could any one kindly give a solution for this. Otherwise I will have to input each these entries in strings.xml and take them to java code using `getResources()getString()`

Thank you.
Tharindu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an IDE in front of me right now, but I think you should be able to do something like R.res.arrays.YOUR_ARRAY_OF_STRINGS.

Comment: But it is only an integer I think, I need the content of the array :( thought there should be an easy way other than getting all array elements reading from 'strings.xml'

Comment: You can do it by doing the following:

String[] arrayContents = getResources.getStringArray(R.array.arrayname);

Answer (score 10):

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.umc_profile_values);
```

worked 4 me!

Answer (score 6):

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] name = res.getStringArray(R.array.name_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">App name</string>
    ...

    <string-array name="scale">
        <item>Excellent</item>
        <item>Good</item>
        <item>Fair</item>
        <item>Poor</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

If you want to get 1 element in array by java

```
String val1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.scale)[0];
```

Or you can get all

```
String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.scale);
```